# lambda linq not join c#

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

I have this query that returns me the names of the users whose `userid` is in `access` table and `users`, what I want is to give me back those `userid` of users who are not in `access`.:

```
 var query = db.Users
      .Join(db.Access, c => c.UserId, o => o.UserId,
       (c, o) => new { c.UserId, c.Name });
```

In sql it´d be something like this:

```
SELECT  Users.Name
FROM     Access INNER JOIN
               Users ON Access.UserId <> Users.UserId
```

What is the `lambda expression` equivalent to the sql script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var exclude = db.Access.Select(p => p.UserId);


var us = db.Users.Where(q => !exclude.Contains(q.UserId)).ToList();


ViewBag.UsersId = new SelectList(us, "UserId", "Name");
```

Finally that is the right answer, the only difference is in the first line.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 6):

Use `Except`

```
var res = db.Access.Except(query);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `! Contains()` like below:

```
//Get Access user ids into an array
var AccessUserIds = db.Access.Select(a => new {a.UserId}).ToArray();

//Users who are not in Access user id array
var Results = db.Users.Where(u => !AccessUserIds.Contains(u.UserId));
```